# Сдвиг при открытии модального окна

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap модальные окна.
Установил на сайт онлайн-консультант и при открытии модального окна пропадает скролл прокрутки и происходит сдвиг бирки (онлайн-консультанта) на ширину скролла.

Что нужно добавить из CSS к этой бирке , чтобы не было сдвига ?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас на сайте шапка с `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: При открытии Bootstrap модального окна , скрывается scroll и в body подставляется padding-right:Xpx (ширина скролла).

Походу к бирке онлайн консультанта , тоже нужно подставлять этот же отступ.

Но как ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668996/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-script

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, поможет один из следующих вариантов:

```
body.modal-open {
  margin-right: 17px;
}
```

```
body[style*="overflow: hidden"] {
  margin-right: 17px;
}
```

Если нет, [подбирай правильный селектор](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714833/178988).

Comment: лучше body.modal-open, имхо

Comment: @humster_spb, ну смотря что скрипт добавляет. Только один из этих вариантов будет работать. Я как-то привык, что обычно появляется инлайном.

Comment: Бутстрап при открытии модалки добавляет body именно этот класс. Поскольку автор уточнил, что использует бутстрап, я и отметил, что вариант с классом, на мой взгляд, оптимальнее

Comment: @humster_spb, ok, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема на сайте.

Решение довольно простое:

```css
html.pum-open.pum-open-overlay.pum-open-scrollable .pum-overlay.pum-active {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
html { overflow-y: scroll !important; }
```

Или вот ещё вариант:

```css
html.pum-open.pum-open-overlay.pum-open-scrollable body>[aria-hidden] {
padding-right: 0 !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
html { overflow-y: scroll !important; }
```

Можно немного пожонглировать и подобрать комбинацию под себя))