# Добавка в script

Tags: javascript, jquery

У Bootstrap при открытии модального окна часть этого скрипта подставляет `padding-right:(x)px` , а при закрытии убирает его.
Как сделать чтобы дополнительно подставлялся этот же отступ к `id="supportTrigger"`
Что и куда добавить ?
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Речь идет о добавлении `padding-right` элементу `body` в случае, когда элемент имеет полосу прокрутки.

У Bootstrap Modal есть [события](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).
На событие `shown.bs.modal` мы устанавливаем `padding-right` элементу `#supportTrigger`

```
$('#myModal')
  .on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var paddingRight = $('body').css('padding-right')
    $('#supportTrigger').css('padding-right', paddingRight)
  })
```

На событие `hidden.bs.modal` обнуляем `padding-right`

```
$('#myModal')
  .on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#supportTrigger').css('padding-right', 0)
  })
```

Comment: Здорово ! Куда это дело встроить ?

Comment: Куда это дело вставить я не могу сказать, я же не видел ваш код. Вот, пожалуйста, [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/jom82g4z/)